# How do I redirect the top/parent page of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iframe

Here's the deal: I have an iframe form within an HTML page. I need to redirect the whole page to a *thank you page* once the form is submitted successfully.

I have something like:

`ContactFormController.prototype.postIndependentForm = function(req, res) {
    //**
      * content
      */
    return res.redirect(301, self.config.redirectTo);
  };`

However, that only redirects the iframe content. I would need something similar to: `window.top.location.href='someUrl'` but applied to nodejs.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated. (I might not be thinking of a proper solution).

Thank you!

Comment: You could always do something like `res.end('<html><body><p>Redirecting...</p><script>window.top.location.href="' + self.config.redirectTo + '"</script></body></html>')`. This is of course assuming that the iframe and parent are of the same origin.

Comment: Never mind, some random characters were copied from stackoverflow. Thanks a lot @idbehold, your answer worked!!